# avfoundation recording is not working while zoomed

Tags: swift, ios8, avfoundation, ios8.1

I am writing a camera app where I am trying to implement zoom on avfoundation. My code is here

`func beginSessionWithBackCameraAndMic(){`

```
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    captureSession.beginConfiguration()

    var err:NSError?

    videoInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.cameraWithPosition(AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back), error: &err)

    if(self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)){
        self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput);
    }

    audioInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audio, error: &err)

    if(self.captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput)){
        self.captureSession.addInput(audioInput);
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput)){
        captureSession.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
    }



    var captureconneciton = movieFileOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var orientation = getOrientation()

    captureconneciton.videoOrientation = orientation



    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)

    previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = orientation

    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    previewLayer?.frame = self.v.bounds

    self.v.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)



    captureSession.commitConfiguration()

    self.captureSession.startRunning()







}
```

@IBAction func record(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    var e = NSErrorPointer()

    video.lockForConfiguration(e);

    video.activeFormat = video.formats[15] as AVCaptureDeviceFormat

    video.videoZoomFactor = 5


    video.unlockForConfiguration()
```

var outputpath = NSTemporaryDirectory()+"output.mov";

```
        var outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputpath)

        var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(outputpath){
            var error:NSError? = nil;
            if (fileManager.removeItemAtPath(outputpath, error:&error) == false)
            {
                print("error saving temp file")
            }
        }

        movieFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
```

}

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
```

//Here I am doing the necessary works saving works to my internal memory

}

On record function I change the active video format which supports zoom but when I got crash like this

`2015-02-17 04:16:22.308 Ourdrum[1379:159045] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - no active/enabled connections.'`

If I just comment these two lines

video.activeFormat = video.formats[15] as AVCaptureDeviceFormat

video.videoZoomFactor = 5

The recording works fine. I have used SessionPresetHigh though.

Can anybody please help !

Thanks

Comment: Hey :) Same problem, you found an answer on that?

Answer (score 1):

try moving those trouble lines

```
video.lockForConfiguration(e);

video.activeFormat = video.formats[15] as AVCaptureDeviceFormat

video.videoZoomFactor = 5

video.unlockForConfiguration()
```

before your line on your beginSessionWithBackCameraAndMic method:

```
self.captureSession.startRunning()
```

you can change the zoom factor anytime you'd like if you lock the configuration but I think you have to set the video format before you start it all up.